# Check Smartphone for existing Social Media Accounts

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, social-media

at the moment I develop an App with flutter and I want to check the Smartphone for existing Social Media Accounts (Facebook, Instagram, LinkedIn, Snapchat,...).
Is there a way to check this, without implementing every API? I don't want to catch the email or profil picture, just the username. 
Maybe there is an URL which opens the profil of the user (if the Social Media App is installed) and one could catch the username?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't know if this is possible without rooting the phone (especially on iOS), and to be honest I sincerely hope it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that directly, and I hope that is not possible, because it feels like a huge privacy hole, in my opinion.

An alternative I can suggest is using Firebase Authentication from Google's [Firebase Backend-as-a-Service](https://firebase.google.com/). From the [Firebase Authentication Service Docs:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)

> The Firebase Authentication SDK provides methods that allow users to sign in with their Google, Facebook, Twitter, and GitHub accounts.